# Headlight issue - keep turning off by themselves

Tags: chevrolet, headlight, impala

So last night I was driving home and after about 10 seconds, my headlights just went out on their own. So I turn off the automatic lights and manually turn my headlights back on and they started working again. For about 15 seconds and then they shut back off. My fog lights stay on and the outer part of my headlights stay on but not the main bulb [I have a 2014 impala](https://www.cargurus.com/Cars/2014-Chevrolet-Impala-Pictures-c23829#pictureId=36505610). Same issue when I try to turn on the high beams, it shuts off after 15 seconds and I’m left driving with fog lights in the middle of the night.

Comment: Have you had the system checked for codes? There may be a control module issue or a sensor failure.

Comment: I was thinking an issue with the body control module (BCM) as well .

Comment: Thinking about this some more, I'm almost positive it has something to do with the BCM. The BCM controls the headlights to where it leaves the headlights on for 15 seconds after you shut your car off. Your descriptions of the light turning off after 15 seconds leaves me to believe the BCM is causing your issue, mainly due to the timing.

Comment: If the bcm is shutting them off you may also want to check how it recieves ignition power. There could be a poor connection or even a bad ignition switch...if that's how this one receive ignition signals

Answer (score 0):

It's actually quite common for LED headlights to turn off automatically after about 15 seconds. This is because the LED lights have a built-in thermal protection mechanism that prevents them from overheating and causing damage or even electrical fires. Essentially, if the internal temperature of the LED headlight reaches a certain point, it will automatically shut off as a safety measure. Additionally, it can also be due to power saving features or faulty wiring. However, if this happens frequently or unexpectedly, it may be worth seeking professional assistance in order to ensure the proper function of your vehicle's lighting system.